# Java split regex non-greedy match not working

Tags: java, regex, non-greedy

Why is non-greedy match not working for me? Take following example:

```
public String nonGreedy(){
   String str2 = "abc|s:0:\"gef\";s:2:\"ced\"";
   return str2.split(":.*?ced")[0];
}
```

In my eyes the result should be: `abc|s:0:\"gef\";s:2` but it is: `abc|s`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.*?` in your regex matches any character except `\n` (0 or more times, matching the least amount possible).

You can try the regular expression:

```
:[^:]*?ced
```

On another note, you should use a constant Pattern to avoid recompiling the expression every time, something like:

```
private static final Pattern REGEX_PATTERN = 
        Pattern.compile(":[^:]*?ced");

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "abc|s:0:\"gef\";s:2:\"ced\"";
    System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(
        REGEX_PATTERN.split(input)
    )); // prints "[abc|s:0:"gef";s:2, "]"
}
```

Comment: "The .*? in your regex macth any character except \n (0 or more times (matching the least amount possible))."
Why shouldn't `:.*?ced` match `:\"ced`?

Comment: I understood now together with the answer of @Bohemian and your link. The algorithm first seeks ":" and **then** it tries to find the minimum matches for ".". I thought it sees this two steps together. So `:[^:]*?ced` is the perfect solution for the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is behaving as expected. The non-greedy match will match as little as it has to, and with your input, the minimum characters to match is the first colon to the next `ced`.

You could try limiting the number of characters consumed. For example to limit the term to "up to 3 characters:

```
:.{0,3}ced
```

---

To make it split as close to `ced` as possible, use a negative look-ahead, with this regex:

```
:(?!.*:.*ced).*ced
```

This makes sure there isn't a closer colon to `ced`.

Comment: If it is true what you tell me, I think then `":.*ced"` should do the trick. But it does exactly the same. Why?
Your solution don't helps me, because the characters between : and ced can be more than 3. What I want, is the smallest match and I thought this is, what non-greedy does.

Comment: But the point is it *does* match non-greedily from the first colon found. So you want the shortest match of colon followed sometime later by ced. I think I can help you :) see edited answer!

Comment: I understand not. Thank you. Your solution is also good. But what do you say to `:[^:]*?ced`? Isn't this also possible?